# Natural phrasing when introducing yourself and the reason you are arriving somewhere

Tags: expressions, politeness, daily-life

I'm looking for a natural expression to introduce myself and the reason I have come to a certain place. In my specific case, I will be going to a school to observe (with an appointment at a specific time), but if I can use this pattern for more general usage, that would be great.

I am thinking of something along these lines:

```
僕はスミス・ジョンと申します。見学にまいりました。
```

This seems simple and safe, but I thought maybe it would be better to join these a single sentence.

```
僕はスミス・ジョンと申しまして、見学にまいりました。
```

(As a side question, would 〜見学に来ております be more natural sounding?)

Alternatively, I have seen a pattern where information about the person is used before their name, as in:

```
僕は、見学にきた、スミス・ジョンと申します。
```

Somehow saying "〜に参った" sounds like it could be misinterpreted so I used "きた" instead. But I may be wrong.

If anyone has any suggestions please let me know.

EDIT: Thinking about this again, I think the "僕は" part really isn't needed. Let me know if I am right about that.

Comment: Yep, you're right about the 僕 part. 2 reasons why don't need to use it. 1) You don't need a subject and 2) 僕 is too casual for the situation implied by the rest of the language in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

My standard would be the following (when I visit companies i just omit the 見学　nount as just say I have the appointment)

> XX時の見学の約束を頂いているスミスと申しますけども

At which point they should respond with something like お待ちしておりました (we were waiting for you (no negative implication) and give you instructions on what to do next

Answer (score 0):

I think you could say...

> 見学に参りました、（ジョン・）スミスと申します。

or maybe...

> X時から見学させていただきます、（ジョン・）スミスと申します。

For more general usage, how about...

> X時に（見学・面接・面談 etc. の / XX様と）お約束をさせていただいております、（ジョン・）スミスと申します。

---

> As a side question, would 〜見学に来ております be more natural sounding?

I think 見学に参りました sounds more natural.

> Thinking about this again, I think the "僕は" part really isn't needed.

You wouldn't need 僕は, but you could use [私]{わたくし} if you wanted to sound formal, as in [私]{わたくし}、X時にお約束をさせていただいております、ジョン・スミスと申します。